Календарь в React.js с выбором даты и времени, аналогичный браузерному input type datetime-local, для мобильной версии
Проблема с реализацией календаря с выбором даты и времени на React в мобильной версии. Меня устраивает функционал мобильной версии, как у обычного input datetime-local, где скроллом выбираются даты, однако на функционале даты и времени все и заканчивается. Нужен абсолютно другой дизайн, у модального окна с выбором даты-времени должны быть другие кнопки, подписи и прочее. Полностью кастомный компонент создать не получилось - цикличная прокрутка времени работала косячно, останавливаться ровно на том месте, где должна быть выбранная дата, тоже не получилось. Искала реактовские библиотеки. Наткнулась на react-mobile-datepicker, но при импорте библиотеки мне выдалось следующее:
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-mobile-datepicker'. '[мой путь]/calendar2/node_modules/react-mobile-datepicker/dist/react-mobile-datepicker.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-mobile-datepicker` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-mobile-datepicker';`

npm i --save-dev @types/react-mobile-datepicker, разумеется, не помогло, и календарь не заработал. А из логов в devTools, когда запустила в браузере, выяснилось, что дальше 17 версии он не поддерживается (у меня 18)
Других решений с кастомным мобильным календарем я не нашла. Если вы знаете, не могли бы подсказать реактовские библиотеки с функционалом мобильного календаря даты-времени? Или, может быть, где-то есть инструкция по самостоятельному созданию такого компонента.

Глупо наверное советовать MUI для таких целей, но в нем такое есть.
